# javax.xml.bind cannot be resolved

Tags: java, xml, eclipse

I have a weird problem with an import I'm using in an Eclipse project. I am importing javax.xml.bind but I have an error saying that it cannot be resolved. My project's compliance is using Java 1.8, my JRE System Library is also 1.8. A friend of mine that is working on the code with me through Github has the same Java configurations in Eclipse but he is not having the same problem as I do. We have tried uninstalling and re installing the JRE for the project and still won't work. Does anyone know what's this all about?

Comment: You might have configured a newer Java JDK/JRE (where `javax.xml.bind` is missing) in _Window > Preferences: Java > Installed JREs_.

Comment: Thanks, that worked just fine

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You might have configured a newer Java JDK/JRE (where `javax.xml.bind` is missing) in *Window > Preferences: Java > Installed JREs*.

**Since Java 11 `javax.xml.bind` is not contained** anymore in the system library and has to be added as a dependency (e.g. [with this one](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api)).

Comment: What the solution add another version of JDK/JRE?

Comment: @Jon Since Java 11 `javax.xml.bind` is not contained anymore in the system library and has to be added as dependency (e.g. [with this one](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api)).

Comment: @howlger, your comment would really improve your answer, imho.

Answer (score 2):

I'm working with Java 17. As mentioned `javax.xml.bind` is missing in newer JDKs.

Step 1: Go to [this link](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api) .

Step 2: Select one of the Versions

Step 3: Copy the contents of dependency tag under Maven tab.

Step 4: Add the copied contents in pom.xml file within `<dependencies> </dependencies>` tags

Now you should be able to see an option to import required libraries.