# The import javax.xml.bind cannot be resolved

Tags: java

Hi where can I find   **javax.xml.bind  -** javax.xml.bind cannot be resolved.

*I have seen the following
[javax.xml.bind cannot be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61177573/javax-xml-bind-cannot-be-resolved)*

Do I need to install another version of JREs?

I have the following?
plugins\org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_15.0.1.v20201027-0507\

thx

Comment: As the package name suggests, this package does not belong to the standard library, but to `javax` ([JAXB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakarta_XML_Binding) to be precise), i.e. to Jakarta (formerly known as JEE). The easiest way to get the needed dependency is by using a dependency management tool like [gradle](https://gradle.org/) or [maven](https://maven.apache.org/). Another possbility would be to download the JAR(s) needed and add it(them) to the classpath.